# CLLocationCoordinate2D distance between two points considering zoom level

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit, cllocation

I'm trying to create a solid clustering mechanism using a subclass of an `MKMapView`. I came across a task that have I've been banging my head against the wall for quite some time now - grouping annotations into a single cluster when they're overlapping with one another. I can get the distance in meters between two annotations, but how can I get that distance relative to a zoom level (latitudeDelta)? Ideally I would like to know when two annotations overlap with each other considering their width and height for example are 40x40.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `convertCoordinate:toPointToView:` to get the location of the actual screen point for an annotation:

```
CGPoint annotationPoint = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:annotation.coordinate 
                                            toPointToView:self.mapView];
```

After that, use your trigonometry skills to find the distance between two points.